Adding entries to "files" section causes electron-builder to fail
I've set up a project with electron-vite which I've gotten to a test version for distribution to some friends.  Running npm run build:win will initiate a build procedure that packages everything into an installer, which is nice.  However the installer does not include a data directory which has three json files with data used by the program.  Looking online the suggestion is to modify electron-builder.yml to include an entry for the folder I want to pack.  If I modify the files section however, it fails to build:

⨯ Application entry file "out\main\index.js" in the "X:\Some\Directory\Project\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar" does not exist. Seems like a wrong configuration.  failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: Application entry file "out\main\index.js" in the "X:\Some\Directory\Project\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar" does not exist. Seems like a wrong configuration.

I've also seen conflicting reports online to edit my package.json instead with a build field and include the paths to package in there, but that also causes the error above if I include a build section.
As mentioned, I've tried modifying electron-builder.yml and package.json to be formatted similar to other peoples and projects suggestions, however any modifications cause build problems.  I've heard something about a double package.json configuration but I don't know what that's about.  I have only the one.
Of note:  The dozens of pages covering the problem I'm having assume I have a build section in my package.json, but it doesn't have one by default.  As I said, adding one causes the build process to fail, the same with the files section in the electron-builder.yml config file.
Failed Output
npm run build:win

> Project@1.0.0 build:win
> npm run build && electron-builder --win --config


> Project@1.0.0 build
> electron-vite build

vite v4.5.2 building for production...
✓ 2 modules transformed.
out/main/index.js  2.38 kB
✓ built in 102ms
vite v4.5.2 building for production...
✓ 1 modules transformed.
out/preload/index.js  0.83 kB
✓ built in 15ms
vite v4.5.2 building for production...
✓ 26 modules transformed.
../../out/renderer/index.html                   0.53 kB
../../out/renderer/assets/index-466810ee.css    2.63 kB
../../out/renderer/assets/index-dec5119b.js   190.38 kB
✓ built in 1.38s
  • electron-builder  version=24.13.3 os=10.0.19045
  • loaded configuration  file=X:\Some\Directory\Project\electron-builder.yml
  • writing effective config  file=dist\builder-effective-config.yaml
  • skipped dependencies rebuild  reason=npmRebuild is set to false
  • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=25.9.8 appOutDir=dist\win-unpacked
  ⨯ Application entry file "out\main\index.js" in the "X:\Some\Directory\Project\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar" does not exist. Seems like a wrong configuration.  failedTask=build stackTrace=Error: Application entry file "out\main\index.js" in the "X:\Some\Directory\Project\dist\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar" does not exist. Seems like a wrong configuration.
    at error (X:\Some\Directory\Project\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\asar\asarFileChecker.ts:7:12)
    at checkFileInArchive (X:\Some\Directory\Project\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\asar\asarFileChecker.ts:31:11)
    at WinPackager.checkFileInPackage (X:\Some\Directory\Project\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\platformPackager.ts:514:7)
    at WinPackager.sanityCheckPackage (X:\Some\Directory\Project\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\platformPackager.ts:562:5)
    at WinPackager.doPack (X:\Some\Directory\Project\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\platformPackager.ts:319:5)
    at WinPackager.pack (X:\Some\Directory\Project\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\platformPackager.ts:140:5)
    at Packager.doBuild (X:\Some\Directory\Project\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\packager.ts:445:9)
    at executeFinally (X:\Some\Directory\Project\node_modules\builder-util\src\promise.ts:12:14)
    at Packager._build (X:\Some\Directory\Project\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\packager.ts:379:31)
    at Packager.build (X:\Some\Directory\Project\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\packager.ts:340:12)
    at executeFinally (X:\Some\Directory\Project\node_modules\builder-util\src\promise.ts:13:14)

package.json (working config)
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A character sheet program for Origins of Mana",
  "main": "./out/main/index.js",
  "author": "Me",
  "homepage": "https://www.electronjs.org",
  "scripts": {
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --fix",
    "start": "electron-vite preview",
    "dev": "electron-vite dev",
    "build": "electron-vite build",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "build:win": "npm run build && electron-builder --win --config",
    "build:mac": "npm run build && electron-builder --mac --config",
    "build:linux": "npm run build && electron-builder --linux --config"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@electron-toolkit/preload": "^2.0.0",
    "@electron-toolkit/utils": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-updater": "^6.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-toolkit/eslint-config": "^1.0.1",
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.3.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.3.1",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^8.0.0",
    "electron": "^25.6.0",
    "electron-builder": "^24.6.3",
    "electron-vite": "^1.0.27",
    "eslint": "^8.47.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.17.0",
    "less": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.9",
    "vue": "^3.3.4"
  }
}

electron-builder.yml (working config)
appId: com.electron.app
productName: Project
directories:
  buildResources: build
files:
  - '!**/.vscode/*'
  - '!src/*'
  - '!electron.vite.config.{js,ts,mjs,cjs}'
  - '!{.eslintignore,.eslintrc.cjs,.prettierignore,.prettierrc.yaml,dev-app-update.yml,CHANGELOG.md,README.md}'
  - '!{.env,.env.*,.npmrc,pnpm-lock.yaml}'
asarUnpack:
  - resources/**
win:
  executableName: Project
nsis:
  artifactName: ${name}-${version}-setup.${ext}
  shortcutName: ${productName}
  uninstallDisplayName: ${productName}
  createDesktopShortcut: always
  oneClick: false
  allowToChangeInstallationDirectory: true
mac:
  entitlementsInherit: build/entitlements.mac.plist
  extendInfo:
    - NSCameraUsageDescription: Application requests access to the device's camera.
    - NSMicrophoneUsageDescription: Application requests access to the device's microphone.
    - NSDocumentsFolderUsageDescription: Application requests access to the user's Documents folder.
    - NSDownloadsFolderUsageDescription: Application requests access to the user's Downloads folder.
  notarize: false
dmg:
  artifactName: ${name}-${version}.${ext}
linux:
  target:
    - AppImage
    - snap
    - deb
  maintainer: electronjs.org
  category: Utility
appImage:
  artifactName: ${name}-${version}.${ext}
npmRebuild: false
publish:
  provider: generic
  url: https://example.com/auto-updates

